# Doctrine add calculated fields

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Right now i have a Profile entity that has a 1:1 relation to an Address entity

if i create the following simple query

```
$this->qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('e')
    ->from($this->_entityName, 'e')
;
```

It return some data like this :

```
firstname: Test
lastname: Bla
gender: male
dateOfBirth: '1972-03-14'
address:
    city: Brussel
    country: BE
```

Which is exactly what i want, but now i want to add an age field.
it works when i do it like this :

```
$this->qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('e','YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) - YEAR(e.dateOfBirth) AS age')
    ->from($this->_entityName, 'e')
;
```

But the result ends up being:

```
0:
    firstname: Test
    lastname: Bla
    gender: male
    dateOfBirth: '1972-03-14'
    address:
        city: Brussel
        country: BE
age: '42'
```

So it puts the age in a different result and puts all the data from the entity in the 0 key.
Now how can i make it so the age just becomes part of the entity data ?

This is how i would like it to be :

```
firstname: Test
lastname: Bla
gender: male
dateOfBirth: '1972-03-14'
age: 36
address:
    city: Brussel
    country: BE
```

And also the result is currently like this because of the JMSSerializer, there are more fields in the entity that are just not serialized but they are all still being fetched from the database...
Is there any way i can make doctrine retrieve only the needed fields while maintaining the same result ?

Comment: Why don't you just modify the serialization to calculate the age on demand? If required, you could also add a dummy member and corresponding getter for that purpose. Doctrine cannot add a member dynamically at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a helper method to your `Profile` entity that would return calculated age:

```
public function getAge()
{
    // calculate age here

    $age = ..... ;

    return $age;
}
```

Comment: yes i could do that , i was just wondering if it is possible to do it at the doctrine level because i need it to be calculated there anyway to filter users by age.

Comment: will this do? - http://www.theodo.fr/blog/2013/11/dynamic-mapping-in-doctrine-and-symfony-how-to-extend-entities/

Comment: seems like it explains how to use traits and how to add doctrine mappings dynamically. But nothing about merging dynamic columns created by sql selects to a result set. 
But thx anyway :) im just using the getter function now like you suggested and adding it to the entity using the serializer

Comment: What if the calculated value is the result of a complex expression that you would like to do in the database and not in PHP?